# How can I use RBF to replace a transaction sent from Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, replace-by-fee

How do I resend a transaction with RBF on a Bitcoin Core node v.19 or v.20? I am running it on Ubuntu.

I tried `bumpfee txid` and got the response that “the transaction is not BIP125 replaceable”. What does that mean?

Comment: Have you tried [`bumpfee`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/bumpfee/) txid ?

Comment: @Prayank yeah it said transaction is not BIP125 replaceable

Answer (score 1):

According to [BIP 125](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0125.mediawiki) which is implemented in Bitcoin Core with one [exception](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21946), only transactions that signal RBF will be replaceable later with higher fee rate and fee.

You can enable RBF for all wallet transactions using `walletrbf=1` in *bitcoin.conf* file however it should be enabled by default.

In GUI there is a checkbox for RBF which can be used for each transaction:

[image: rbf-checkbox]

If you are using RPC commands for creating transaction, most of them have arguments to enable RBF. Example: `"replaceable" : true` in `fundrawtransaction`

Comment: OP's question is about how to make Bitcoin Core signal BIP125, I suspect.

Comment: Got it. This solved it, abandontransaction :-)

Comment: @HereshAriai That won't do anything.